# Creating a nested dictionary where inner values are lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

So I want to create a nested dictionary of lists where the inner value is a list that allows duplicates:

```
d = {'45678':{'ant':['N4', 'N4', 'P3', 'P3']}}
```

This is what I have so far but can't figure out how to append a list to the inner value:

```
d={}
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    for l in f.readlines()[4:]:
        peaks = l.split()
        if '1' in peaks[5]:
            d.setdefault(peaks[0], {})['ant'] = [peaks[7]]
```

Which returns:

```
{'20065037': {'ant': ['N4']}}
```

My question is how can I append a list as the inner value in the nested dictionary?

Comment: Use `list.append()` method. `d.setdefault(peaks[0], {})['ant'].append(peaks[7])`

Comment: What does the input file look like? I'm not sure where the other values are supposed to come from. Appending to a list in Python is as simple as `l.append(whatever)`.

Comment: Wouldn't the brackets around `peaks[7]` in `d.setdefault(peaks[0], {})['ant'] = [peaks[7]]` make it a list?

Comment: @Kasramvd. You'd probably want to `setdefault` on the inner dictionary as well.

Comment: @e9e9s Yes, `[peaks[7]]` is a list. But that doesn't seem to be the problem you're having.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The inner dictionary doesn't seem to have more than one key, thus there's no need to another `setdefault()`.

Comment: @Kasramvd. There is if you want to create a new dictionary and new list in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code is basically sound (in terms of processing the file), you should use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) on the inner dictionary and [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) to the list.

```
d={}
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    for l in f.readlines()[4:]:
        peaks = l.split()
        if '1' in peaks[5]:
            d.setdefault(peaks[0], {}).setdefault('ant', []).append(peaks[7])
```

Currently, you are always creating a new list using `[peaks[7]]` instead of giving an option to append.

Comment: Yes this is exactly it.  I was having trouble figuring how how to set the setdefault on the inner dictionary.  Will upvote in 6 minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have figured out what you're trying to do.

Does this help?

```
d.setdefault(peaks[0], {}).setdefault('ant', []).append(peaks[7])
```

If not, please explain what the file looks like or something else about what you're trying to do.